# RecyclerView Item extend beyond boundaries

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a fixed height for its items. These items have a expanding menu that does not fit within the ViewHolder, so I would like for it to extend beyond its parents width and height. You can see the issue here:

[image: sample]

Is this even possible to achieve?

Comment: Did you try (not sure if this will do) `android:clipChildren="false"` on the recyclerview or one of the views (don't blindly add it everywhere, for performance can suffer) but try it on different places (the viewholder layout, the actual recycler view, the recyclerview container, etc. Not sure if it does it.

Comment: that does fix it but the items arent clickable outside of their boundaries :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this question as I faced the same issue with an animation that should expand beyond the RecyclerView item bounds.

@Martin Marconcini's comment suggesting to add `android:clipChildren="false"` to the RecyclerView helped me a lot.

I had to add it also to the item's layout which is a FrameLayout in my case.
After adding that, my animation successfully expanded beyond it's parents bounds.